# How to find out rowindex when fire dropdown event inside gridview

Tags: asp.net

I am using two dropdownlist in gridview.  Total 5 to 7 rows in gridview. 
  Bind ProductId and product name in First Dropdown. when select product that time databound in second dropdown.
  so how to findout row number when fire dropdown's event.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I assume the property you're looking for is [`GridViewRow.RowIndex`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridviewrow.rowindex.aspx). To get the reference to the row from the [`SelectedIndexChanged`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listbox.selectedindexchanged.aspx) event from your DropDownLis(s), you can use it's [`NamingContainer`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.control.namingcontainer.aspx) property:

```
private void DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
   DropDownList ddl = (DropDownList)sender;
   GridViewRow row = (GridViewRow)ddl.NamingContainer;
   int rowIndex = row.RowIndex;
   // if you want to get the reference to the other DropDown in this row
   DropDownList ddl2 = (DropDownList)row.FindControl("DropDownList2");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can handle SelectedIndexChanged event of DropDownList.

```
protected void DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        GridViewRow gvr = (GridViewRow)((DropDownList)sender).Parent.Parent;
        string rowNumber= GridView1.DataKeys[gvr.RowIndex].Value.ToString();
}
```